# Expo remote debugger strange warnings

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

I know that this question may sound funny, but since today I had no problems when debugging my React-Native applications using expo-go on my Android Device. Right now I got some strange warnings that have never appeared before, and I have no clue how to 'fix' them.
For debuging purposes I always scan a QR code on my Android Device that gets generated from `expo start`.

[image]

Comment: What I've also noticed is that my application is no more auto reloading the changes, I have to manually click R everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall expo.

Open expo metro builder/bundler in a brpwser and try connecting to tunnel and scan the qr code in an android device. This worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me at all. Moreover connecting via tunel in my situation is suuuuuper slow :/ I don't know what the hell is happening there...